# Is there any way to get more information of user like friends birthday,current_location?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get user's friend information + user's personal information in one graph api call, using all the permissions.

permissions : user_birthday,friends_birthday,friends_current_location
I am doing this graph api call : https://graph.facebook.com/me?birthday,friends?fields=birthday,current_location&access_token.

This is not working for me.  Is there any way i can access above provided info in one api call. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad!

It works. Use this call to get the birthdays. You can add current_location to the fields as well:

```
$funnel = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=name,gender,birthday&access_token='.$at);
```